# MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path unmet requirement in TeamCity on Linux/Mono agent

Tags: c#, linux, mono, teamcity-8.0

I have a c# web service built in VS2013 which I have deployed on mono and working fine. I have just setup an indentical linux box as an agent of my TeamCity installation - the problem is that I have an unmet requirement "MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path". Any ideas on how I can meet this requirement? I'm hoping to avoid a windows based agent...

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I had an incorrect build runner selected in TeamCity in configuration. I changed runner type to "MSBuild" and version to "Mono xbuild 4.0" and platform to "x64". Finally you need to point to your .sln file for "Build File Path" - everything is working now

Comment: You should accept your own answer, I had the same situation.